# Does android have an atomic counter that can be shared among multiple applications?

Tags: android

We have multiple applications in the appstore would like to sync data between them via content providers.  For consistency issues we would like to have a global counter to implement something like a lamport clock. Is there any mechanism to do this?

Note that account manager is not an option for us.

Comment: I don't think you can use a global counter, unless you write it to a shared file available for all applications (which will be available for other apps too)

Comment: Lamport clocks, based on a quick skim of the definition, are for coordination between multiple disparate machines, each of which would have an independent clock. For multiple processes on the same machine, the system clock should suffice. "Does android have an atomic counter that can be shared among multiple applications?" -- only what you implement yourself via various IPC mechanisms.